# How to have an #ifdef block only evaluate when VS Code intellisense is reading it?

Tags: c++, macros, intellisense

I am working with emscripten, which uses some macros that VS Code IntelliSense does not like. This is not unusual. So what I'd like to do is this:

```
#ifdef INTELLISENSE_IS_READING_THIS
    #define PROBLEMATIC_MACRO
#endif
```

That way, I can keep the macros as is but VS code will stop whining.

<sub>Sad thing is I remember solving this exact problem in Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense - with Microsoft's very own resource files - but unfortunately, it appears I did not ask this on stack overflown and instead solved it myself, so now I can't find it anymore.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! Found it. Just needed to craft a query that excludes all the questions about IntelliSense NOT reading or defining defines.

This is the way:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
    #define EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
#endif
```

And this also works, but may also evaluate in Microsofts compiler:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
#endif
```